Apache Tika 2.0.9 programm ffmpeg and exiftool not found?
I use an JavaFX Maven Project to use Apache Tika Version 2.9.0.
The Java Test program will be finished and all methods that I create will done right.
I have in the log file a lot of DEBUG errors and Idon't know why?
I habe spent many hours to clear the problem.
Here's an excerpt of the logfile
2024-04-03 14:56:12 [main] DEBUG org.apache.tika.parser.external.ExternalParser - exception trying to run  ffmpeg
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffmpeg": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074) ~[?:?]
...
2024-04-03 14:56:12 [main] DEBUG org.apache.tika.parser.external.ExternalParser - exception trying to run  exiftool
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "exiftool": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1140) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1074) ~[?:?]
...


The message says that ffmpeg and exiftool are not found.
This is my tika-config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"/>
        <!-- Aktiviere den ExternalParser für ffmpeg -->
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.external.ExternalParser">
            <params>
                <param name="enable" type="bool">true</param>
                <!-- Aktualisierter Pfad zur ffmpeg.exe-Datei -->
                <param name="command" type="string">"D:\Tools\ffmpeg-6.1.1\bin\ffmpeg.exe"</param>
            </params>
        </parser>
        <!-- Aktiviere den ExternalParser für exiftool -->
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.external.ExternalParser">
            <params>
                <param name="enable" type="bool">true</param>
                <!-- Aktualisierter Pfad zum Verzeichnis von exiftool -->
                <param name="command" type="string">"D:\Tools\exiftool.exe"</param>
            </params>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
    <detector>
        <detector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultDetector"/>
    </detector>
</properties>

I tested the path of the programms in a console ant it worked fine?
I don't know what I can do now?
Thanks for Help
I have downloaded new copies of the ffmpeg and exiftool and installed them.
I tested it in a console to run and both tools work fine.
I tested the permissions, no problems with permissions
I tested that the tika-config.xml will be loaded, it loaded.

Try replacing the backslashes "" with forward slashes "/". Is "D:" a local or a network drive?

Also try to remove the " from the file paths
